# Add elements to a Dataframe with for loop python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I would like to add elements to an empty Dataframe by using for loop. I tried the following:

```py
df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B"])

for i in df.veggies.unique():
    df_special = df.loc[(df.color== 0) & (df.shape== i)]
    number_of_veggies = df_special.shape[0]
    df_result["A"] = df_result["A"].append(i)
    df_result["B"] = df_result["B"].append(number_of_veggies)
```

I received the error:

**`TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`**

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't append a string to a dataframe. Try this..

```py
df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B"])

for i in df.veggies.unique():
    df_special = df.loc[(df.color == 0) & (df.shape == i)]
    number_of_veggies = df_special.shape[0]
    new_row = {"A": i, "B": number_of_veggies}
    df_result = df_result.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```